# Cant get Times New Roman font to work with mpdf 6

Tags: php

All config is default as it is deifned in mpdf 6.0

In result I got font-family: 'sans-serif'; in output pdf file.

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8','A4','','timesnewroman',20,15,58,25,20,10);
body {font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help. [Source](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/choosing-a-configuration-v6-x.html)

```
body {
    font-family: ctimes;
}
```